# "obvious edges" detection to get distance

Tags: php, python, node.js, machine-learning, canny-operator

I am looking for a way to solve the problem below in Python,php or javascript.

I would like to know what approach / algorithm / ML Model 
to use to get me on track 
and being able get these pink edges detected and then mesure distances.

is Canny edge detection a good approach ?
or ultrametric contour map ?

I have no clue right now.

Here is an illustration of what i'm trying to achieve

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looklike **OpenCV** contour detecttion is the Way to go.

doesn't look so bad as a starting point :

[image]

using this a first step

```
ret,thresh1 = cv2.threshold(img,220,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
ret,thresh2 = cv2.threshold(img,220,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
```